# Counting words, lines and characters from a file in C

Tags: c, file, count

I attempted to do a program that counts the number of words, lines and characters in a .txt file. When I run the program, it always shows 0 for both lines and words and gives me a wrong number for the character count.
If anyone can single out the mistakes for me that would be great. Thank you in advance =D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x[1000];
    int w=0, l=0, c=0; //counters of words, lines and characters (respectively)

    FILE *inp;

    inp=fopen("text.txt", "r"); //opening the file

    while(fscanf(inp, "%s", x)!=EOF)    //checking if the end of the file
    {
        fscanf(inp, "%s", x);
        c++;
        if (fscanf(inp, "%s", x)==' '){
            w++; 
            c--;
        }
        else if (fscanf(inp, "%s", x)=='\n'){
            l++;
            w++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of lines is: %d\n", l);
    printf("The number of words is: %d\n", w);
    printf("The number of characters is: %d\n", c);

    fclose(inp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `'%s"` in `fscanf(inp, "%s", x)` drops leading white-space without saving them in `x`.  This mean the character count will not include white-spaces.

Comment: How can you read words and count characters? Say you read the words "foo" followed by "bar". How can you know how many characters that was?

Comment: `if (fscanf(inp, "%s", x)==' ')` is most curious.  `fscanf()` returns the number of item scanned (or EOF).  Why compare this item count (which will be 1 or less in this case) to `' '`?  Same for `fscanf(inp, "%s", x)=='\n')`.

Comment: You probably want to replace the `fscanf()` for `fgetc()`. Get and sum one character at a time; every time you get a space, tab, or new line increment word counter; every time you get a new line increment lines counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare `fscanf(..,..,x)` to the read data. The read data is in `x`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x[1000];
    int w=0, l=0, c=0; //counters of words, lines and characters (respectively)

    FILE *inp;

    inp=fopen("text.txt", "r"); //opening the file

    int character_read;
    while( (character_read = fgetc(inp)) !=EOF)    //checking if the end of the file
    {
        // One character was read
        c++;
        // Check if it is a separator char (count another word)
        if (   character_read == ' ' 
            || character_read == '\n'
            || character_read == '\t' )
        {
            w++; 
        }
        // Check if it was a newline (count a new line)
        if (character_read == '\n')
            l++;


    }

    printf("The number of lines is: %d\n", l);
    printf("The number of words is: %d\n", w);
    printf("The number of characters is: %d\n", c);

    fclose(inp);

    return 0;
}
```